Ask a coding problem for the equivalence of unconstrained Optimization with L1 Regularization
I recently read a statistics paper. It has an unconstrained problem:
$$\min_\theta F(\theta)+\lambda || \theta||_1$$, where $$F(\theta)=L(\theta)+\frac{\rho}{2}|h(W(\theta))|^2+ \alpha h(W(\theta))$$
$\rho$ is a penalty parameter and $\alpha$ is a dual variable.
It uses the L-BFGS-B algorithm. It says the L-BFGS-B algorithm can be directly applied by casting the above problem into a box-constrained form:
$$\min_\theta F(\theta)+\lambda || \theta||1  \iff  \min{\theta^+ \geq0, \theta^- \geq0} F(\theta^+-\theta^-)+\lambda \mathbf{1}^T (\theta^++\theta^-) $$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all ones.
My question is why this is equivalent?
My first observation is that  any real number x can be written as the difference of two non-negative numbers: $x = x^+ - x^-$, where $x^+ = \max(x,0)$ and $x^- = \max(-x,0)$, and we have $|x| = x^+ + x^-$. It looks like a proof.
The coding from that paper is
adj <- function(w) { # ?
    w <- as.matrix(w)
    w.pos <- w[1:(length(w)/2),]
    w.neg <- w[((length(w)/2)+1):(length(w)),]
    dim(w.pos) <- c(d,d)
    dim(w.neg) <- c(d,d)
    W <- w.pos - w.neg
    return(W)}

But I notice that in the proof, one of $x^+$ and  $x^-$ must be $0$. But in the above coding, there's no such constraint. This is what I feel confused.
In the small proof, one of $x^+$ and  $x^-$ must be $0$. Is this should a constraint that we  need to explicitly enforce in the optimization problem?

Hi: By definition, one of them, $x^{+}$ or $x^{-}$ will always be zero. It is true that the code in the paper doesn't seem to be following the definition given. But maybe that could be code for some different reference-example in the paper ?  Or maybe later in the code, it gets fixed ? The code there is clearly a subset of larger piece of code.
